# limits.conf is not working

Tags: ubuntu, pam, limit

I'm trying to set default niceness/priority for a user's processes on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS in `limits.conf` and everything I write in `limits.conf` is simply ignored. Hard nice, soft nice, hard priority, soft priority, `- priority`, doesn't matter it just don't work.

`session    required   pam_limits.so` in `/etc/pam.d/su` was uncommented by default and I also tried to reboot the system after making changes in `limits.conf`.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Example 1:

```
root             soft    nice            -16
root             hard    nice            -17
```

When I log into a server with `ssh root@host.name` I expect to see in `top -o -NI` output at least one process (my bash login session) with a NI of `-16` or `-17`. None of the processes had this value of nice.

Example 2:

```
user123          soft    nice            5
user123          hard    nice            5
```

When I request a "http://host.name/benchmark.php" I expect to see in `top -o %CPU` output the PHP FastCGI process with niceness of `5`. I see a PHP FastCGI process with niceness of `0`

Example 3:

```
user123          soft    priority        25
user123          hard    priority        25
```

When I request a "http://host.name/benchmark.php" I expect to see in `top -o %CPU` output the PHP FastCGI process with priority of `25`. I see a PHP FastCGI process with priority of `20`

Example 4:

```
user123          -       priority        25
```

When I request a "http://host.name/benchmark.php" I expect to see in `top -o %CPU` output the PHP FastCGI process with priority of `25`. I see a PHP FastCGI process with priority of `20`

Comment: Give us an example line from limits.conf and what exactly should work and doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated a question with an examples of what I have tried to set in `limits.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1. The documentation for `nice(2)` explains that "*The  range  of  the  nice  value is +19 (low priority) to -20 (high priority)*". When you set the entry in `limits.conf` to `-16`/`-17` that's effectively an upper limit that can be reduced to the values I assume you saw.

Examples 2, 3, 4. Your webserver is probably not calling PAM to change userid, so `limits.conf` isn't referenced.